# Docker Compose File for Node.Js app that wraps a static frontend

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I am trying to figure out how to setup a docker-compose file to build my node.js image and my frontend image

my Node.js App wraps my Vue.js Frontend and serves the static files.

***Folder Structure***

[image]

### In my docker-compose.yml

***root of project***

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    env_file:
        "./app/frontend/.env"
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "myusername/backend"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./app/frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "myusername/frontend"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "backend"
```

### Backend DockerFile

***/app***

```
FROM node:12.18.3

LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="This is the base docker image for Backend"
LABEL maintainer = ["test@testuser.com"]

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
RUN ls
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

### DockerFile for Frontend

***/app/fronted***

```
FROM node:12.18.3

LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="This is the base docker image for Frontend"
LABEL maintainer = ["test@testuser.com"]

WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am not sure if this is correc, I can successfully build the images, but can't navigate to any of the ports I exposed

```
docker-compose config
```

does return the contents of my docker-compose.yml file

#### Note

at the root of /app and app/frontend
there is a .dockerignore file that just contains

`node_modules`

Comment: Thank you for responding, could you elaborate as I am unsure of what you mean

Comment: hmm, okay if I comment out image, it just carries on with saying `Building backend`

Comment: It doesent have anymore output other than `Building backend`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228814/discussion-between-codebling-and-mitch).